# LibGDX FreeType font blurry

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, freetype

I'm generating my font dynamically using the screen height percentage and set percentages (Obviously multiplied by density's in the future.

Some notes.
I'm reading from an OTF file.
Using the latest version of LibGDX (Version 1.2.0)

I have the following problem:
(Large breaks in the font and looks very blurry, but only on **medium**. **Large** and **small** look very sharp)

[image: Bad font]

My Preset font sizes:

```
//Font sizes, small, med, large as a percentage of the screen.
    public static float
            FONT_SIZE_LARGE = 0.175f,
            FONT_SIZE_MEDIUM = 0.06f,
            FONT_SIZE_SMALL = 0.04f;
```

My font generator settings

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
this.generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(filename));
```

Creating the actual font:

```
//Create a new font and add it to available font sizes.
public BitmapFont createFont(float size, float color)
{
    this.parameter.size = Math.round(size);
    BitmapFont bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    bitmapFont.setColor(color);
    listOfFonts.add(new FontStorage(bitmapFont, size));
    return bitmapFont;
}
```

Now I've tried a few things on different devices but still have the same issue. I'm thinking it could be because it's not the power of 2? (Do font's need to be a power of 2 to be even?)

The fonts are drawn on many different screen resolutions, so making three bitmap fonts of a certain size is out of the question.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: If using a single BitmapFont in various sizes, you need to use mipmapping for it to look good at all sizes. And probably MipMapLinearLinear for the minFactor.

Comment: I'm using multiple Bitmap font sizes to match the screen res exactly but can you please link or explain this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you're doing. Mipmapping is unnecessary the way you're doing this. I don't think power of two is your issue either. To the best of my knowledge, non-POT only puts you at risk of slower performance (and possibly pure black textures on certain devices if you are on an old version of libgdx and using OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1). I haven't used the font generator much, so I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: I'm on the newest version, completely lost to as why it's doing this if it's matching the res exactly.

I can send you the entire source code if you wish?

Comment: I recommend going to the libgdx.com forums. You'll likely find someone there that knows the answer. I don't have the first inkling what could cause this issue so I'm equally lost as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out, there are 3 settings you need to set if you want ultimate clear fonts.

The first two are just before creating it from file (Can be OTF or TTF) and they are:

```
//Make sure you ceil for your current resolution otherwise you'll be nasty cut-offs.
this.parameter.size = (int)Math.ceil(size);
this.generator.scaleForPixelHeight((int)Math.ceil(size));
```

The next step is setting a magnify and minifies filters. (For scaling if you want too, I'm not because I'm drawing almost pixel perfect). Here's the code anyhow:

```
this.generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(filename));
this.parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest;
this.parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest;
```

This will give you super nice crisp font on any resolution. GL.

Comment: I cannot for another day.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I've heard that setting mipmapping in magnification has no use. Mipmapping is for minification only.